# Find combination of nested JSON keys

Tags: javascript, json, combinations, permutation

I am having some trouble solving this issue without using nested for-loops. I would like to do it using recursion.

Given the following object:

```
{
  "Color": {
    "Black": [],
    "White": []
  },
  "Effect": {
    "30W": [],
    "40W": [],
    "60W": []
  }
}
```

The code should compute each combination of Color and Effect and add a number in the list such that the following is produced:

```
{
  "Color": {
    "Black": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    "White": [
      4,
      5,
      6
    ]
  },
  "Effect": {
    "30W": [
      1,
      4
    ],
    "40W": [
      2,
      5
    ],
    "60W": [
      3,
      6
    ]
  }
}
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
const func = (object, entries) => {
    for (let prop in object) {
        let counter = 0;
        const objLength = Object.keys(object[prop]).length;
        for (let key in object[prop]) {
            console.log(key + counter)
            for (let i = 0; i < entries.length / objLength; i++) {
                object[prop][key].push(entries[counter]);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

However, this does not return the desired output. I think it is because of the inner-most for loop condition.

Comment: What is the logic behind the numbers? What if there was another color; black white -- and then green.

Comment: @chrwahl The numbers are there to be able to reconstruct a unique combination. In practice, they correspond to a product id, where a product is either black or white or green and effect of 30w or 40w or 60w

Comment: You have provided an example of `ojbect`, but what would `entries` look like?

Comment: You provided some desired output without providing a sample input. Why? Also, could you shed some light on how and why the output should look like the desired? What are you building? Can you share some more context?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That is incorrect. Sample input is given in the code block under "Given the following object:"
The output is a permutation of the keys. The object is arbitrary (and so are the values in the associated lists), it may have deep nesting, or shallow. They all end in lists. In the example, observe the number 4. It constructs  a unique combination of the keys

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to create your JavaScript object and convert it to a string.

```
// creating your object with attributes.  Objects in objects or whatever you
// need
 var obj = new Object();
   obj.name = "Dale";
   obj.age  = 30;
   obj.married = true;

   dataToAdd.forEach(function(item, index) {
     item.married = false;
   })
```

// Then convert it to a string using the following code

```
var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(jsonString);
```

Comment: No, since object keys are unique we would not have a bijective mapping between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question by considering the space of each attribute key. Then it is just a matter of finding the cartesian, and adding values accordingly:

```js
const cartesian =(...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));

function diy(jsonObj, counter) {
    let permObj = []
    let keys = Object.keys(jsonObj)

    keys.forEach(key => {
        permObj.push(Object.keys(jsonObj[key]))
    });

    permObj = cartesian(...permObj)

    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < permObj.length; j++) {
            jsonObj[keys[i]][permObj[j][i]].push(j + counter);
        }
    }

    return jsonObj;
}
```